# Break PHP array into 3 columns

Tags: php, arrays, split, break

I'm trying to break a PHP array into 3 columns (has to be columns, not rows) so it would look something like this:

```
Item 1     Item 2     Item 3
Item 4     Item 5     Item 6
Item 7     Item 8     Item 9
Item 10................
```

The best approach I can think of would be to break the main array into 3 arrays, 1 for each column although I can't work out the best approach to do this - more specifically the criteria I could use to generate the 3 arrays.

Comment: How should the items be ordered within these columns? (should it be 123,456,789 or 147,258,369)

Comment: "Has to be columns, not rows"...? But you are showing *rows* of data in your example...?

Comment: @deceze imagine the data in three divs, 1 for each column. That isn't rows.

Comment: With the data you're showing it hardly makes a difference. A regular table view could do. What exactly do you want to achieve? Why is it important to think of the data in columns, not rows of 3 columns? Why does one column need to be one `<div>`? Why does it need to be a `<div>` and why didn't you specify this in the question?

Comment: @deceze It needs to be columns, not rows as what I'm trying to display is images of equal widths but indeterminate heights. The idea is that they will display in order across the rows, but so that the gaps between each image vertically is always equal, they will be grouped by columns. The fact that I didn't specify that it needs to be in `<divs>` is irrelevant as I had already explained that it needs to be in columns, not rows.

Comment: Due to the lack of specificity in the question (missing: clearly structured input, a, coding attempt, and exact desired output), the comments that sought feedback and didn't really get it, the wide spectrum of solutions that contain differing outcomes, the accepted answer that gives a snippet that only isolated a single column and another that may or may not create properly ordered columns (and doesn't make accommodation for rows with less than 3 cells ... I'm voting as Unclear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use this:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($array as $value) {
  if ($i % 3 === 0) {
        echo $value . '<br />';
    }
   $i++;
}
```

Or when using html table:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <?php 
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($array as $value) {
      if ($i % 3 === 0) {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
      echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
      $i++;
   }
   ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For me, I had to check if the `$i  !=  0`  together with the `$i % 3 == 0` . (Using === didn't worked). But thanks for your help.

Comment: Big time saver, this one! Just installed it on a site with heavy jQuery behind it, and this solution makes over 3,000 people (on a polling page) very happy the coming month.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) to extract a section of an array, so:

```
$newArray = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($oldArray); $i += 3) {
    $newArray[] = array_slice($oldArray, $i, 3);
}
```

Edit: As @deceze points out, this does the same thing as [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk). (I knew PHP would have something built-in.) So use that instead!

Comment: Although this shows how to split the array, it doesnt solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @deceze: That's an *answer*. But yes I am ;)

Comment: The question is how can i output my array in 3 columns, not how can i split it in 3 different arrays. It is a suggestion on how to solve it, and not an optimal one imho.

Comment: This is not what he wants. He wants 1, 4, 7 and 10 in the first column.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approach although the idea was that the arrays would contain non-consecutive elements, at positions (1,4,7)(2,5,8) & (3,6,9) etc.

Comment: @minitech Do you mean as rows? Rows would not work for intended use of this though.

Comment: @RobM: It doesn't matter in the end, just iterate in the other direction... rows = columns

Comment: @minitech I don't quite see what you mean - for what I need columns is the only way of achieving it.

Comment: @RobM: Okay... do you have a loop? Or are you passing the array into a library? What's the context?

Comment: @minitech Basically I have x amount of images held in a database, all of the same width but varying heights. I need them to display in the order they were added in rows of three whilst at the same time, all gaps between images being uniform in each column.

Comment: That's what I said! @minitech

Comment: @RobM: Are you looping with `for`? Just reverse the loops. Are you looping with `foreach`? Change it to `for`.

Comment: @minitech: I've posted my own solution below - let me know what you think

Comment: @minitech The output is simply a foreach loop for each array in separate divs. I guess ultimately you could bypass separating the original array into three and just use the first foreach loop directly in each column.

Comment: @minitech Why use for? The array is of an indeterminate size although wouldn't ever be of a size where foreach would be noticeably slower than for.

Comment: @RobM: No, so you can loop through the columns.

Comment: @minitech can you please give an example - I don't see how `for`is of any advantage over `foreach` in this instance

Comment: @RobM: [It's for visualizing it in the other direction!](http://codepad.org/MRhklbap)

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = array(); 
$columns = 3;

echo "<table><tr>";

for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
{
 if($i%$columns == 0)
  echo "</tr><tr>";
 echo "<td>".$data[i$]."</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

There you go, it just outputs another row when you get to your column count. You might need to add some logic when the data isnt a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 2):

Using array_chunk you can split array :

```
$rows = array_chunk($yourArray, '3'); // 3 = column count;
foreach ($rows as $columns) {
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    foreach ($columns as $column) { 
        echo "<div class='column'>$column</div>"; 
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately array_chunk does not split them in the order specified in the question. It will put 1,2,3 in the first column. I wish array_chunk had a option to distribute them left to right.

Answer (score 1):

When considering your question topic it's first impression is"Column" and I think you needed to focus on visual aspects. "How to display your array as three columns" May be my idea is wrong. But I think you wanted that. Just check following example if my thought is correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
?>
<body>
<div style="width:300px">
<ul>
    <?php foreach($arr as $itm) {?>
    <li style="list-style:none;float:left;width:80px;"><span style="font-size:36px;"><?php echo $itm;?></span></li>
    <?php }?>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just display the array as a single column?

Comment: No. These three columns control with CSS. You don't need to do that programmatically. It's just uses width & float CSS attributes with un-ordered list.

Comment: This again would effectively produce rows - for what I need, columns are the only way it will work.

Comment: This is absolutely the best way to do it, unless there is some unmentioned reason why you can't use divs and floats. The advantages of this have been written about ad nauseum, but basically, it is more flexible, maintainable, accessible, better for SEO, and more besides.

Comment: @pspahn. Have you checked this? This code produce 3 columns as he need since the width of the dive is 300px and list item width is 80px.

Comment: @PrasadRajapaksha - I misunderstood the OP. I was looking for content that was sorted from top to bottom, not from left to right. Edit your answer and I will undo.

Comment: @pspahn No. This is my answer to OP's question. Not for yours. So this answer may not be a fix for your question. Ask it as a separate question. You may get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Having just thought about it, this should achieve what I want - whether it's the fastest method though, I'm not sure:

```
$array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....)


$column1 = array();
    $i = 2;

foreach($array as $value) {
    if ($i++ % 3 == 0) {
        $column1[] = $value;
    }
}


$column2 = array();
    $i = 1;

foreach($array as $value) {
    if ($i++ % 3 == 0) {
        $column2[] = $value;
    }
}

$column3 = array();
    $i = 0;

foreach($array as $value) {
    if ($i++ % 3 == 0) {
        $column3[] = $value;
    }
}
```

EDIT: The same as above although using a single foreach loop:

```
$array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....)


    $column1 = array();
    $column2 = array();
    $column3 = array();
    $i = 2;
    $j = 1;
    $k = 0;


foreach($array as $value) {
    if ($i++ % 3 == 0) {
        $column1[] = $value;
    }
    if ($j++ % 3 == 0) {
        $column2[] = $value;
    }
    if ($k++ % 3 == 0) {
        $column3[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer as it outputs the data in different columns, just as you suggested. You dont need to store it in different arrays, you can just start a new row after each Nth element.

Comment: @TJHeuvel Although in three columns, does this not ultimately return the results in rows? I need the results returned in three separate divs.

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

echo '<table>';

$colNum = 3;
$regNum = 10;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $regNum; $i++) {

    if (($i % $colNum) == 1) {

        echo "\n\t".'<tr>';

    }

    echo "\n\t\t".'<td>'. $i .'</td>';

    if (($i % $colNum) == 0 or $regNum <= $i) {

        echo "\n\t".'</tr>';

    }

}

echo "\n".'</table>';
```