# Split php array into different div iteratively

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to break a PHP array of 9 array items into 3 divs. My array is displayed as:

```php
$array = array("item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5", "item 6", "item 7", "item 8", "item 9")
```

This might be a previously asked question but I couldn't find a working solution.
I tried what I saw on a similar question here on [Break PHP array into 3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696796/break-php-array-into-3-columns) but it didn't achieve it as I wanted.

The snippet of what I want to achieve is below...

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: colum;
  gap: 80px;
}

.wrapper div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <p>Item 4</p>
    <p>Item 7</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <p>Item 5</p>
    <p>Item 8</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Item 3</p>
    <p>Item 6</p>
    <p>Item 9</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45710505/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/21261547/2943403

Comment: Demo: [Chunk - Transpose - Implode](https://3v4l.org/Z4P8q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, maybe this solution will work for you:

```php
<?php 
  $data = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6', 'Item 7', 'Item 8', 'Item 9'];
  $columnLimit = 3;
  $columns = array_fill(0, $columnLimit, []);
   
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $columns[$key % $columnLimit][] = $value;
  };
?>


<div class="wrapper">
  <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
  <div>    
    <?php foreach($column as $item): ?>
      <p><?=$item?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

A working example can be seen here: https://onlinephp.io/c/bd015

Comment: _array_fill_ and the _foreach_ can be replaced by: _$columns = array_chunk($data, $columnLimit);_

Comment: @lukas.j [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) is not suitable because it splits the array sequentially, i.e. `[['Item 1, 'Item 2', 'Item3'], ['Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'], ['Item 7', 'Item 8', 'Item 9']]`, but we need to distribute the elements as they are fill evenly, i.e. `[['Item 1, 'Item 4', 'Item7'], ['Item 2', 'Item 5', 'Item 8'], ['Item 3', 'Item 6', 'Item 9']]`.

Comment: You are of course right. I did not read the question properly. Sorry for that.

Comment: `array_chunk()` can be an appropriate component of a solution; its data just needs to be transposed.